# Intercept HOME key while dialog is opened in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

How to intercept HOME key while dialog is opened on screen in android.??

Comment: In your question itself I can see many questions. What you have tried so far? What is the problem you are facing? etc...

Comment: When Dialog is opened on screen, during that time, how to intercept Home Key?

Comment: Your question is soon going to be closed due to lack of explanation. So, better is to modify your question and be specific to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution of my question. Now i can successfully intercept HOME button the way I want. I have write all the steps in this blog :
https://nishandroid.blogspot.com/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html

Comment: What you have mentioned in your  blog its not working in my case i am using ics.

Answer (score 2):

According to android implementation you can not catch Home button key event using simple API like OnKeyListener().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage dialog appearance properly in an `Activity` by figuring out whether a user moved out of your `Activity` on purpose (hit the `back` or `home` buttons) 
or unintentionally by having some other Activity hiding yours (e.g. incoming call) 
use `onUserLeaveHint`.

e.g.:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    mDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: `onUserLeaveHint` is *not* called for unintentional interruptions. From the documentation: " For example, when the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be called on the activity being interrupted. "

Answer (score -1):

Set [DialogInterface.OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.html) of the dialog

```
new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
                        //do something
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Above method is not useful. Cannot resolve issue by applying this method.

Comment: @aNi i recently use KeyDown Method and KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME to detect home key press  but it never given to application of android it is for Android System Framework.